# Vuejs: Always rendering the same component even if the route path is different

Tags: vuejs2

that's my first post, sorry in advance for my english that's not my first luangage. So here is my problem: i can figure out why vuejs rendering the same component even if the path is different.

Here is my vue-router file and then the file where my router-view is called:

basically when i refresh my page, that send me to the same component even the url (path) is different. I try several thing like beforeach,..etc but nothing seems to work.

Any help will be appreciate.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import store from "@/store";

// import MultiSteps from '../component/MultiSteps.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },

  {
    path: "/multisteps",
    name: "Multisteps",
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },

    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/MultiSteps.vue"),
    // component: MultiSteps
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/Register.vue"),
    // component: MultiSteps
  },
  // {
  //   path: "/dashboard",
  //   redirect: (to) => ({
  //     name: "Dashboard",
  //     query: { slug: to.params.slug },
  //   }),
  // },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    redirect: { name: "ListTask" },
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: ":slug",
        name: "Profile",
        props: true,
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/Profile.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: ":slug",
        name: "ListTask",
        props: true,
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/ListTask.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: ":slug",
        name: "HelpDesk",
        props: true,
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/HelpDesk.vue"),
      },
    ],
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/Dashboard.vue"),
    // component: MultiSteps
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!store.state.isConnected) {
      next({ name: "Home" });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    console.log("skip");
    next(); // does not require auth, make sure to always call next()!
  }
});


export default router;
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      class="min-h-screen flex flex-auto flex-shrink-0 antialiased bg-gray-50 w-full text-gray-800"
    >
      <div class="flex flex-col top-0 left-0 w-64 bg-gray-900 screen shadow-lg">
        <div class="flex items-center pl-6 h-20 border-b border-gray-800">
          <!-- <img
            src="https://scontent.fmnl13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/117334168_2606581056324669_4951020710334194218_o.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_eui2=AeFo4bRKc5SfTQvzhwotnTaOfj1P6rO41HF-PU_qs7jUcU1pCerqu3HUsOB0yKyJQwnrgz8Au7GZADcpedo6WgM4&_nc_ohc=DWpkI3p4RSUAX_hKF_Y&_nc_ht=scontent.fmnl13-1.fna&oh=c13c63ee952123b14f0da72b99ccecc8&oe=6087FEC5"
            alt=""
            class="rounded-full h-10 w-10 flex items-center justify-center mr-3 border-2 border-blue-500"
          /> -->
          <div class="ml-1">
            <p
              class="ml-1 text-md font-medium tracking-wide truncate text-gray-100 font-sans"
            >
              JED DYLAN LEE
            </p>
            <div class="badge">
              <span
                class="px-2 py-0.5 ml-auto text-xs font-medium tracking-wide text-blue-800 bg-blue-100 rounded-full"
                >User</span
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden flex-grow">
          <ul class="flex flex-col py-6 space-y-1">
            <li class="px-5">
              <div class="flex flex-row items-center h-8">
                <div
                  class="flex font-semibold text-sm text-gray-300 my-4 font-sans uppercase"
                >
                  Dashboard
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <router-link
                class="router-link"
                :to="{
                  name: 'Profile',
                  params: { slug: 'profile' },
                }"
              >
                <a
                  href="#"
                  class="relative flex flex-row items-center h-11 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-700 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-200 border-l-4 border-transparent hover:border-blue-500 pr-6"
                >
                  <span class="inline-flex justify-center items-center ml-4">
                    <svg
                      class="w-5 h-5"
                      fill="none"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                      <path
                        stroke-linecap="round"
                        stroke-linejoin="round"
                        stroke-width="2"
                        d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                  <span
                    class="ml-2 font-semibold text-sm tracking-wide truncate font-sans"
                    >Profile</span
                  >
                </a>
              </router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <router-link
                class="router-link"
                :to="{
                  name: 'ListTask',
                  params: { slug: 'listtask' },
                }"
              >
                <a
                  href="#"
                  class="relative flex flex-row items-center h-11 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-700 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-200 border-l-4 border-transparent hover:border-blue-500 pr-6"
                >
                  <span class="inline-flex justify-center items-center ml-4">
                    <svg
                      class="w-5 h-5"
                      fill="none"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                      <path
                        stroke-linecap="round"
                        stroke-linejoin="round"
                        stroke-width="2"
                        d="M20 13V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v7m16 0v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5m16 0h-2.586a1 1 0 00-.707.293l-2.414 2.414a1 1 0 01-.707.293h-3.172a1 1 0 01-.707-.293l-2.414-2.414A1 1 0 006.586 13H4"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                  <span
                    class="ml-2 font-semibold text-sm tracking-wide truncate font-sans"
                    >Liste des tâches</span
                  >
                </a></router-link
              >
            </li>
            <!-- <li class="px-5">
              <div class="flex flex-row items-center h-8">
                <div
                  class="flex font-semibold text-sm text-gray-300 my-4 font-sans uppercase"
                >
                  Settings
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> -->
            <li>
              <router-link
                class="router-link"
                :to="{
                  name: 'HelpDesk',
                  params: { slug: 'helpdesk' },
                }"
              >
              <a
                href="#"
                class="relative flex flex-row items-center h-11 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-700 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-200 border-l-4 border-transparent hover:border-blue-500 pr-6"
              >
                <span class="inline-flex justify-center items-center ml-4">
                  <svg
                    class="w-5 h-5"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      stroke-width="2"
                      d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00-7-7z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <span
                  class="ml-2 font-semibold text-sm tracking-wide truncate font-sans"
                  >Help desk</span
                >
              </a>
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <router-view :key="$route.path" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");
html {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sound like you have this behavior in `/dashboard` because you have `redirect` to `ListTask`

Comment: Actually it's not even that view who 's rendered. it's always the 'Profile' view. I don't know why.  Basically i want  when i refresh to be redirected to the same view I was on previously..

Comment: Try to replace dynamic path `path: ":slug",` with static name

Comment: thanks, that works but why because in one of my other project where i used  this method i didn't had this problem..